# How to import and call .mjs files during runtime inside a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a Vue app ( based on Vite ) and want to dynamically import external files. The application doesn't know about them during build time because those files contain pluggable components. My app fetches a configuration from an external API and this contains an array of "sources" ( I can decide if those sources should be paths or urls ), where each source is pointing to a component ( living in a .mjs file )

During deployment you should be able to place a .mjs file "somewhere" in the dist directory and the application should try to import it based on a configured path.

---

I already successfully tried to import a component from an .mjs file right next to the .vue file but didn't try the desired way. For simplicity the example only tries to import a .mjs file with a function, because if this works, the component way will work too

---

Inside ./dist I created a file foo.mjs

```
const foo = function() {
    console.log("Success from Foo");
}

export { foo }
```

and inside ./dist/assets I created a file bar.mjs

```
const bar = function() {
    console.log("Success from Bar");
}

export { bar }
```

In my Vue app I'm trying to call them like so

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted} from "vue";

onMounted(async () => {
  console.log("trying to call function from external file");

  try {
    const { foo } = await import("/foo.mjs");

    foo();
  } catch {
    console.log("foo failed");
  }

  try {
    const { bar } = await import("/assets/bar.mjs");

    bar();
  } catch {
    console.log("bar failed");
  }
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately the app crashes with the error

> Failed to resolve import "/foo.mjs" from "src/App.vue". Does the file exist?

Is it possible to fix the code or do I have to request those files from an external file server via HTTP ( so the configuration contains url sources )?

Comment: This is potential XY problem that has better chances solved in some other way. Don't import it in a module that is supposed to be bundled. If you really think you need to leave some scripts unbundled (this is doubtful decision for Vue apps), load them the usual way, i.e. with <script>. "do I have to request those files from an external file server via HTTP" - you'll have the same problems with them being evaluated, it's not enough to fetch script body. Can be solved with SystemJS, for example.

Comment: Yes I think you will need to fetch the scripts via http, maybe by adding dynamically a `<script>` tag in the dom. `import`, whether it is static or dynamic, expects an accessible file from their location, so in the browser if it's a client-side only SPA.

Comment: I added some more details to my question, not sure if this helps. I have full control over the deployment ( security reasons ) and just want to know if I really need an external file server or not :)

Comment: Even if you need to dynamically import some js/vue files at runtime, from the response of an http call, you can still bundle these files. Make sure they are bundled into an isolated chunk and use dynamic import like you tried, but these files will be present in the final dist folder without you needed to manually include them.

Comment: @Kapcash I'm sorry but I didn't understand your previous comment. It is not possible for me to bundle all the files during a build step